# PHP fopen("filename", w) creates files with ~1

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite

I am trying to write a file in PHP. So far it works "kind of".

I have an array of names in the format {Rob, Kevin, Michael}. I use the line of code

```
foreach($Team as $user)
 {
print_r($user);
    //create a file for each user
    $file = fopen("./employee_lists/".$user, 'w');
    //I have also tried: fopen("employee_lists/$user", 'w');
    // ... ... ...
    //write some data to each file.
 }
```

This works as expected: The print_r shows "Rob Kevin Michael", however, the filenames are saved are as follows: ROB~1, KEVIN~1, MICHAE~1

When I'm going on to use these files later in my code, and I want to relate the usernames of "Rob" to ROB~1, I'll have to take some extra step to do this. I feel like I'm using fopen incorrectly, but it does exactly what I want minus this little naming scheme issue.

Comment: What OS are you using? Windows?

Comment: What is the exact value of `$user`? The problem description seems to suggest the host system doesn't use long file names, which is ridiculous and I suspect impossible - I kind of doubt PHP would compile on a system that doesn't simply because of age. Maybe this is because `$user` contains an invalid character for use in file names (my best guess would be a new line) and this is a side effect, although I'm sure `fopen()` should fail completely in that scenario. Try `$file = fopen("./employee_lists/".trim($user), 'w');`

Comment: Have you tried using an extension to your file name ? Like $file = fopen("./employee_lists/".$user.".txt", 'w');

Comment: I'm running Windows7, but the code is running on a Linux system. RHEL4 If I'm not mistaken.

$Team is the array of names [0]=>Rob, etc. Thereby making $user one of those array elements in the foreach()

Comment: Well DaveRandom, Go ahead and write that down as an answer so I can mark it. the trim() function fixed it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your `$user` variable contains an invalid character for file system paths (my best guess would be a new line).

Try:

```
$file = fopen("./employee_lists/".trim($user), 'w');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should sanitize $user before using it a as file name.

```
$pattern = '/(;|\||`|>|<|&|^|"|'."\n|\r|'".'|{|}|[|]|\)|\()/i';
// no piping, passing possible environment variables ($),
// seperate commands, nested execution, file redirection,
// background processing, special commands (backspace, etc.), quotes
// newlines, or some other special characters
$user= preg_replace($pattern, '', $user);
$user= '"'.preg_replace('/\$/', '\\\$', $user).'"'; //make sure this is only interpreted as ONE argument
```

By the way, it's a bad idea using an user name for a file name. It's better to use a numeric id.